# Image gallery with bootstrap, with bigger image

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a boostrap image gallery. SO if you klick on an image a bigger one will be pop-uped.

I try it like this(html/css):

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <link href="~/Content/ShowMoreImages.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
        {

            @model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 img-thumbnail">

                <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" />

            </div>


            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->



        }
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('li img').on('click', function () {
                var src = $(this).attr('src');
                var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';
                $('#myModal').modal();
                $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(img);
                });
                $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
                });
            });
        })

    </script>
}
```

But if I click on a imgage , nothing happens.

so my question is: how to make the bootstrap image gallery working?

Thank you

This is how you will see the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the modal out of your `foreach` loop, otherwise you'll end up with multiple element with the same id of `myModal`.

**After change:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <link href="~/Content/ShowMoreImages.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
        {

            @model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 img-thumbnail">

                <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" />

            </div>

        }
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

</div>
```

Secondly, that link tag should probably be included in the `head` section of your document - but it shouldn't have an impact on the outcome.

Lastly, and most importantly, you'll need to fix your javaScript by targeting the correct element, instead of `li img`:

**JavaScript after change:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.row img.img-responsive').on('click', function () { // <-- notice the selector change
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';
            $('#myModal').modal();
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#myModal .modal-body').html(img);
            });
            $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
            });
        });
    })
```

**Note:** I used `.img-responsive` but I recommend you create a specific class for targeting the images that are going to be clickable.

---

Also worth noting, you should move the event handler for `hidden.bs.modal` outside the click event handler like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.row img.img-responsive').on('click', function () { // <-- notice the selector change
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';
            $('#myModal').modal();
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#myModal .modal-body').html(img);
            });
        });

        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
        });
    })
```

---

The code could use further clean up:

1. The modal is reused often enough to warrant its own variable
2. The image can be updated before the modal is shown, so we can remove that event handler

Here's what that looks like:

**Final JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $myModal = $('#myModal'); // <-- since we're using it in a few places

    $('.row img.img-responsive').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            src = $this.attr('src'),
            html = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive" />';

        updateModalBody($myModal, html);

        $myModal.modal();
    });

    // Resetting the content of the modal once it's hidden
    $myModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        updateModalBody($myModal, '');
    });

    // Helper function to update modal body
    function updateModalBody($modal, html) {
        $modal.find('.modal-body').html(html);
    }
})
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaut4929/2/)**

Comment: Hi technophobia, thank you.  the pop up is showing, but if I click now elswhere then  pop up will stick on the screen, it doest dissapear, only after refresh the pop is gone

Comment: @hallohallo Open up your browser console, do you see any errors?

Comment: No I dont see any errors. But can I sent you email? My email is: niels.fischereinie@gmail.com. Iv add a picture

Comment: You have some other ideeers? Becasuse I dont see any errors

Comment: @hallohallo I've updated the answer and included a JSFiddle to show you your updated code working.  Have a look.

Comment: Thank you technophobia!!

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code, you have assigned the onclick function to `li img` selector, but your img tags are not inside li tags.

Looking at your JavaScript code, the html output should be something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><img src="img1"></li>
<li><img src="img2"></li>
...
</ul>
```

You need to modify your code to give similar output.

Comment: HI Bibekdahal, thank you for your answare, Yes, I know, but apparently I cant use li in my cshtml, otherwise the images are not displaying correct, so that is why I use divs, but if I change in javascript this line: $('div img').on('click', function () { then it also doesnt work